# Add bullets in jquery dbpasCarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have jquery slider dbpasCarousel but there no option bullets how i can add bullet option in dbpasCarousel ???

```
$.fn.dbpasCarousel.options = {
    itemsVisible: 2,  //for smooth movement, leave at a minimum 2 items out of view
    slideDelay: 500,  //milliseconds
    autoSlide: 0,     //0-off 1-on
    autoDelay: 5000,  //milliseconds
    hoverPause: 1,    //0-off 1-on
    imgCaption: 1,    //0-off 1-on
    onComplete: null  //callback function
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation (https://github.com/dbpas/dbpasCarousel), it seems that paging your carousel items with bullets is not implemented, so you have to do it manually, or use another plugin (there are many jQuery carousel on the web, simple Google "jQuery carousel paging" for example)